# Is there a way to limit the number of sessions opened for an Okta application?

Tags: session, limit, okta

I'm posting this and researching Google at the same time.

Is there a way to limit the number of sessions a user can open for an Okta application?  Right now, we have internal users hammering our cluster because some users are opening several tabs to our website.

Because of an auto-refresh option we coded, it's possible we're getting thousands of queries a minute and since this is a small cluster (only 8 servers right now), our database lags when this happens.

I didn't see anything in the admin Okta view but perhaps someone knows something that I don't know or I didn't see in the Okta UI for our application.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the link from the [Okta site](https://support.okta.com/help/answers?id=906F0000000I04FIAS&feedtype=SINGLE_QUESTION_DETAIL&dc=xSAML&criteria=OPENQUESTIONS&).  It doesn't look like they support session limits.